hang analysis of edge.exe
my edge.exe hung when I right clicked in the address bar.
I did a memory dump with procdump -ma -h {pid}.
When I open the memory dump with windbg, I get:
0:000> !analyze -v -hang
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Exception Analysis                                   *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************


KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1

    Key  : Analysis.CPU.mSec
    Value: 202

    Key  : Analysis.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 1271

    Key  : Analysis.IO.Other.Mb
    Value: 9

    Key  : Analysis.IO.Read.Mb
    Value: 2

    Key  : Analysis.IO.Write.Mb
    Value: 47

    Key  : Analysis.Init.CPU.mSec
    Value: 4265

    Key  : Analysis.Init.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 5743925

    Key  : Analysis.Memory.CommitPeak.Mb
    Value: 284

    Key  : Failure.Bucket
    Value: APPLICATION_HANG_cfffffff_win32u.dll!NtUserGetClipboardData

    Key  : Failure.Hash
    Value: {eab0f5e2-9d73-1b5f-dce1-511d65e146c8}

    Key  : Timeline.OS.Boot.DeltaSec
    Value: 146558

    Key  : Timeline.Process.Start.DeltaSec
    Value: 52978

    Key  : WER.OS.Branch
    Value: ni_release

    Key  : WER.OS.Version
    Value: 10.0.22621.1

    Key  : WER.Process.Version
    Value: 126.0.2592.87


FILE_IN_CAB:  msedge.exe_240712_084801.dmp

COMMENT:  
*** "C:\Program Files\SysinternalsSuite\procdump.exe" -ma -h 24228
*** Hung window detected: 405e2

NTGLOBALFLAG:  0

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0

CONTEXT:  (.cxr;r)
rax=00000000000010e6 rbx=000000d84b9fc4d7 rcx=000000000000000d
rdx=000000d84b9fc430 rsi=000000d84b9fc590 rdi=00006dd805c9d620
rip=00007ffddd9f3174 rsp=000000d84b9fc3e8 rbp=000000d84b9fc440
 r8=0000000000400000  r9=00000000003017f8 r10=0000000000301808
r11=00000000ae6821ed r12=aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa r13=000000d84b9fd1f0
r14=000000000000000d r15=000000d84b9fd260
iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na po nc
cs=0033  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000246
win32u!NtUserGetClipboardData+0x14:
00007ffd`dd9f3174 c3              ret

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  (.exr -1)
ExceptionAddress: 0000000000000000
   ExceptionCode: 80000003 (Break instruction exception)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 0

FAULTING_THREAD:  0000615c

PROCESS_NAME:  msedge.exe

WATSON_BKT_EVENT:  AppHang

BLOCKING_THREAD:  000000000000615c

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xcfffffff - <Unable to get error code text>

EXCEPTION_CODE_STR:  cfffffff

DERIVED_WAIT_CHAIN:  

Dl Eid Cid     WaitType
-- --- ------- --------------------------
   0   5ea4.615c Unknown                

WAIT_CHAIN_COMMAND:  ~0s;k;;

STACK_TEXT:  
000000d8`4b9fc3e8 00007ffd`df30ba7f     : 00000000`00000000 00007ffd`df283925 00000000`00000001 00007ffd`4105a100 : win32u!NtUserGetClipboardData+0x14
000000d8`4b9fc3f0 00007ffd`3acbd740     : 000000d8`4b9fc4d7 00007ffd`00000000 00004d0c`d3f23edd 00000000`00000008 : user32!GetClipboardData+0x9f
000000d8`4b9fc480 00007ffd`3b523124     : aaaaaaaa`aaaaaaaa 00000000`00000008 fffffffc`00000000 00007ffd`32172e96 : msedge!EdgeLaunchBrowserToHandleBackgroundTaskEvent+0x401720
000000d8`4b9fc530 00007ffd`3a665464     : 00000000`00000400 000000d8`4b9fcd40 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : msedge!argon2_encodedlen+0x50edc4
000000d8`4b9fc6f0 00007ffd`34f17802     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 000000d8`4b9fd230 00006dd8`0c3db840 : msedge!CreateTestWebClientProxy+0x29d914
000000d8`4b9fd0e0 00007ffd`351f1310     : 000000d8`4b9fd170 000000d8`4b9fd138 aaaaaaaa`00000000 aaaaaaaa`aaaaaa00 : msedge!CreateSmartScreenClient+0x20c572
000000d8`4b9fd120 00007ffd`351f1172     : 00000000`00000000 00007ffd`351f1123 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000001 : msedge!RelaunchChromeBrowserWithNewCommandLineIfNeeded+0x23e560
000000d8`4b9fd300 00007ffd`3508b1aa     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00004d0c`d3f229bd 00000000`00000000 : msedge!RelaunchChromeBrowserWithNewCommandLineIfNeeded+0x23e3c2
000000d8`4b9fd350 00007ffd`3508af63     : 00006dd8`1475bae0 00006dd8`082a5a00 fffffffc`00000000 fffffffc`00000000 : msedge!RelaunchChromeBrowserWithNewCommandLineIfNeeded+0xd83fa
000000d8`4b9fd3e0 00007ffd`350b4538     : 00000000`00000001 00000000`0000e95b 00006dd8`1475bae8 00000000`00000070 : msedge!RelaunchChromeBrowserWithNewCommandLineIfNeeded+0xd81b3
000000d8`4b9fd450 00007ffd`34f9e3f3     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000018 00006dd8`13e188f0 00000000`00000000 : msedge!RelaunchChromeBrowserWithNewCommandLineIfNeeded+0x101788
000000d8`4b9fd4c0 00007ffd`34f9e355     : 00007ffd`40eceeb0 00000000`00000020 00007ffd`32eb9430 00007ffd`327f0db8 : msedge!CreateSmartScreenClient+0x293163
000000d8`4b9fd520 00007ffd`34f9e2c1     : 00006dd8`13e188f0 00006dd8`14933e10 00000000`00000000 00007ffd`35756f8f : msedge!CreateSmartScreenClient+0x2930c5
000000d8`4b9fd580 00007ffd`398700e6     : 00000000`00000000 00004d0c`d3f22e9d aaaaaaaa`aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa`aaaaaaaa : msedge!CreateSmartScreenClient+0x293031
000000d8`4b9fd5d0 00007ffd`3986fd7d     : 00000040`000003e0 aaaaaaaa`aaaaaa00 00000000`00000000 00000570`00000a00 : msedge!CrashForExceptionInNonABICompliantCodeRange+0x28f6b86
000000d8`4b9fd660 00007ffd`398994f3     : 000000d8`4b9fd778 00000000`00000000 00000570`00000a00 00004d0c`d3f22dad : msedge!CrashForExceptionInNonABICompliantCodeRange+0x28f681d
000000d8`4b9fd740 00007ffd`398632e7     : 00006dd8`08924ff0 000000d8`4b9fd950 aaaaaaaa`aaaaaa00 00007ffd`348687f2 : msedge!CrashForExceptionInNonABICompliantCodeRange+0x291ff93
000000d8`4b9fd780 00007ffd`3486869b     : 000000d8`4b9fd950 000000d8`4b9fda50 000000d8`4b9fd838 00007ffd`349e824c : msedge!CrashForExceptionInNonABICompliantCodeRange+0x28e9d87
000000d8`4b9fd7f0 00007ffd`349e8381     : 00004d0c`d3f2229d 00006dd8`14933e78 00000000`00000000 000000d8`4b9fd938 : msedge!IsSandboxedProcess+0x2839aab
000000d8`4b9fd840 00007ffd`349e8029     : 00000016`0000034f 4453c000`00000000 aaaaaa01`41b00000 aaaaaaaa`aaaaaa00 : msedge!IsSandboxedProcess+0x29b9791
000000d8`4b9fd890 00007ffd`349e7d99     : ffffffff`44780000 ffffffff`ffffffff ffffffff`ffffffff ffffffff`ffffffff : msedge!IsSandboxedProcess+0x29b9439
000000d8`4b9fd910 00007ffd`349e7c47     : 000000d8`4b9fda50 000000d8`4b9fe258 00006dd8`14933e10 00006dd8`1406c000 : msedge!IsSandboxedProcess+0x29b91a9
000000d8`4b9fd9b0 00007ffd`3a808faa     : 42800000`44780000 42800000`44780000 000000d8`4b9fda68 00000002`00000030 : msedge!IsSandboxedProcess+0x29b9057
000000d8`4b9fda20 00007ffd`398609fd     : 00006dd8`0f0560b0 00007ffd`3478afff 00006dd8`0b50a840 00007ffd`39859f6c : msedge!CreateTestWebClientProxy+0x44145a
000000d8`4b9fdba0 00007ffd`3486869b     : 000000d8`4b9fdd80 000000d8`4b9fe180 000000d8`4b9fdc68 00007ffd`349e824c : msedge!CrashForExceptionInNonABICompliantCodeRange+0x28e749d
000000d8`4b9fdc20 00007ffd`349e8381     : 00004d0c`d3f226cd 00006dd8`037f2f98 00000000`00000000 000000d8`4b9fdd68 : msedge!IsSandboxedProcess+0x2839aab
000000d8`4b9fdc70 00007ffd`349e8029     : 00004d0c`d3f226fd 00006dd8`067004c0 00006dd8`037f2f40 000000d8`4b9fdd70 : msedge!IsSandboxedProcess+0x29b9791
000000d8`4b9fdcc0 00007ffd`349e7d99     : 000000d8`4b9fe180 00007ffd`3488c9c2 00006dd8`037f5a00 00007ffd`3493b9f0 : msedge!IsSandboxedProcess+0x29b9439
000000d8`4b9fdd40 00007ffd`349e7c47     : ffffffff`ffffffff 00006dd8`14024bc0 000000d8`4b9fe180 00006dd8`037f5a00 : msedge!IsSandboxedProcess+0x29b91a9
000000d8`4b9fdde0 00007ffd`349e79bb     : 00000000`000001eb 00007ffd`336c23a9 aaaaaaaa`aaaaaaaa d9852248`d9ae3e8b : msedge!IsSandboxedProcess+0x29b9057
000000d8`4b9fde50 00007ffd`349e77fc     : 000000d8`4b9fdfd0 00007ffd`336c230d 00000000`00000000 7fffffff`ffffffff : msedge!IsSandboxedProcess+0x29b8dcb
000000d8`4b9fdef0 00007ffd`34da359c     : 00007ffd`3fda099f 00000000`00000027 000000d8`4b9fdf78 00000000`00009939 : msedge!IsSandboxedProcess+0x29b8c0c
000000d8`4b9fdf30 00007ffd`34da3517     : 000000d8`4b9fe180 00007ffd`34a45c56 00000022`1ef3fcf3 00007ffd`34a45eee : msedge!CreateSmartScreenClient+0x9830c
000000d8`4b9fdfa0 00007ffd`34a4559a     : 00000000`00000000 000001db`c4a48420 00000000`00000000 00007ffd`df87a6a2 : msedge!CreateSmartScreenClient+0x98287
000000d8`4b9fe020 00007ffd`34bc8345     : 00007ffd`40eceeb0 00000000`00000001 00007ffd`32eb9430 00007ffd`327f0db8 : msedge!IsSandboxedProcess+0x2a169aa
000000d8`4b9fe320 00007ffd`34bc77ca     : aaaaaaaa`aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa`aaaaaaaa 000001db`c53e9b20 00007ffd`411427a0 : msedge!IsSandboxedProcess+0x2b99755
000000d8`4b9fe3a0 00007ffd`34775f0d     : 00000000`00000000 00007ffd`df2a665a aaaaaaaa`aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa`aaaaaaaa : msedge!IsSandboxedProcess+0x2b98bda
000000d8`4b9fe450 00007ffd`34775e7f     : 40000000`00000000 aaaaaaaa`aaaaaaaa 00005457`2e3e80e3 aaaaaaaa`aaaaaaaa : msedge!IsSandboxedProcess+0x274731d
000000d8`4b9fe4b0 00007ffd`df2989a1     : 00004d0c`d3f21e3d 00002994`00221420 00000000`00000000 00000000`80000022 : msedge!IsSandboxedProcess+0x274728f
000000d8`4b9fe4e0 00007ffd`df298461     : 00000000`00000000 00007ffd`34775e70 00000000`000405e2 000000d8`4b9fe750 : user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0x2d1
000000d8`4b9fe640 00007ffd`35357765     : 000000d8`4b9fe750 00002994`00000000 00000000`00000001 000000d8`4b9fe750 : user32!DispatchMessageWorker+0x1f1
000000d8`4b9fe6c0 00007ffd`35590001     : 000000d8`4b9fe8f0 00007ffd`33b80e57 00006dd8`02225aa0 00007ffd`4105a100 : msedge!RelaunchChromeBrowserWithNewCommandLineIfNeeded+0x3a49b5
000000d8`4b9fe860 00007ffd`33b80c28     : 00000000`00000000 00002994`002781e0 00000000`00000000 000001db`c4a1cb48 : msedge!RelaunchChromeBrowserWithNewCommandLineIfNeeded+0x5dd251
000000d8`4b9fe8d0 00007ffd`33901555     : 00002994`002781e0 000000d8`4b9feba0 000000d8`4b9feb88 000000d8`4b9fea48 : msedge!IsSandboxedProcess+0x1b52038
000000d8`4b9fe950 00007ffd`34661314     : aaaaaaaa`aaaaaa00 aaaaaaaa`aaaaaa00 aaaaaaaa`aaaaaa00 00000000`00000000 : msedge!IsSandboxedProcess+0x18d2965
000000d8`4b9fea00 00007ffd`31b8f07a     : 000000d8`4b9fea87 00007ffd`33430000 01000000`00000000 000000d8`4b9feba0 : msedge!IsSandboxedProcess+0x2632724
000000d8`4b9fea70 00007ffd`31b8e06d     : 000000d8`4b9fecb0 00002994`002781e0 aaaaaaaa`aaaaaaaa 000000d8`4b9fec30 : msedge!ChromeMain+0x1249a
000000d8`4b9feb20 00007ffd`31b8d599     : 00000000`00000004 00007ffd`3210820e 00000000`00000000 00004d0c`d3f213ad : msedge!ChromeMain+0x1148d
000000d8`4b9fec70 00007ffd`31b7e839     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : msedge!ChromeMain+0x109b9
000000d8`4b9fede0 00007ffd`31b7e099     : 00000000`00000000 00004d0c`d3f215ad aaaaaa01`00000004 00007ffd`31c66918 : msedge!ChromeMain+0x1c59
000000d8`4b9fef50 00007ffd`31b7d541     : 00002994`002582d0 00007ffd`31b859b9 000000d8`4b9ff210 00002994`002781e0 : msedge!ChromeMain+0x14b9
000000d8`4b9ff1b0 00007ffd`31b7cea9     : 00007ff6`190e0000 000000d8`4b9ff5d0 000075dc`0024c190 000000d8`4b9ff410 : msedge!ChromeMain+0x961
000000d8`4b9ff240 00007ff6`19126831     : 00007ff6`193939d0 00007ffd`31b7cbe0 00000000`00000201 000075dc`002741b0 : msedge!ChromeMain+0x2c9
000000d8`4b9ff570 00007ff6`1912447d     : 00000000`ffffff00 00007ff6`19160110 00000000`ffffff01 00007ff6`190e0000 : msedge_exe!MainDllLoader::Launch+0x373
000000d8`4b9ff800 00007ff6`192091a2     : 00007ff6`193670a0 00007ff6`19209219 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : msedge_exe!wWinMain+0x40d
000000d8`4b9ffd30 00007ffd`df15257d     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000800 80000000`00000800 : msedge_exe!__scrt_common_main_seh+0x106
000000d8`4b9ffd70 00007ffd`e024af28     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x1d
000000d8`4b9ffda0 00000000`00000000     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x28


STACK_COMMAND:  ~0s ; .cxr ; kb

SYMBOL_NAME:  win32u!NtUserGetClipboardData+14

MODULE_NAME: win32u

IMAGE_NAME:  win32u.dll

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  APPLICATION_HANG_cfffffff_win32u.dll!NtUserGetClipboardData

OS_VERSION:  10.0.22621.1

BUILDLAB_STR:  ni_release

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

IMAGE_VERSION:  6.2.22621.3880

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {eab0f5e2-9d73-1b5f-dce1-511d65e146c8}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------

The hang thread is 615c according the !analyzer output.
Top of the stack is the GetClipboardData function. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getclipboarddata
The function takes only one UINT parameter.
If we uf the top of the stack:
0:000> uf win32u!NtUserGetClipboardData+0x14
win32u!NtUserGetClipboardData:
00007ffd`dd9f3160 4c8bd1          mov     r10,rcx
00007ffd`dd9f3163 b8e6100000      mov     eax,10E6h
00007ffd`dd9f3168 f604250803fe7f01 test    byte ptr [SharedUserData+0x308 (00000000`7ffe0308)],1
00007ffd`dd9f3170 7503            jne     win32u!NtUserGetClipboardData+0x15 (00007ffd`dd9f3175)  Branch

win32u!NtUserGetClipboardData+0x12:
00007ffd`dd9f3172 0f05            syscall
00007ffd`dd9f3174 c3              ret

win32u!NtUserGetClipboardData+0x15:
00007ffd`dd9f3175 cd2e            int     2Eh
00007ffd`dd9f3177 c3              ret

I thought I could the shared data struct with
dt KUSER_SHARED_DATA 00000000 7ffe0308 but that reveals only garbage (mostly zero values).
And I ran !locks and !critsec - but nothing returned.
Several questions:

Is the address of the UINT parameter this: 00007ffd 4105a100?
How can I check the content of the user shared data struct?
How can I narrow down the root cause of the hang?


If you look carefully you'll see that the context indicates the RET as the next instruction to be executed, thus the thread is stuck inside the syscall (it's now in kernel mode). The SharedUserData has nothing to do with the bug, the flag is used only in very specific circumstances related to hypervisors (its easier for an HV to catch interruptions than syscalls). 1st param in rcx, thus it's now in r10 (the code moves rcx to r10 because the syscall instruction clobbers rcx). Root cause is now in kernel land, not much to analyze in user-mode. Probably and wait that is never satisfied.

Thanks for the answer. If I could repro the issue, I would need a full machine kernel memory dump or would a procdump -mk {pid} enough to get the needed data?

Do you work at Microsoft, or why do you want to find the root cause of the hang? If you can't change the source code, what is it worth?

curiosity :-) I think it's always fun to understand something :D

A deadlock in the GetClipboardData() function does not necessarily indicate an issue with the hung application. Instead, a totally different application may hang. This is due to delayed rendering.
Demo: create a Windows Desktop application in Visual Studio with the following code. After running, use a text editor and press Ctrl+V to insert "something" from the clipboard. The text editor will hang for a minute. In my case (Notepad++) it's hung in User32!GetClipboardData+5e.
#include <windows.h>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

void RenderClipboardData(HWND hwnd) {
    // Simulate deadlock. 10 seconds should be enough for displaying the "not responding" indicator
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::minutes(1)); 
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {

    switch (uMsg) {
    case WM_RENDERFORMAT:
        if (wParam == CF_TEXT) {
            RenderClipboardData(hwnd);
        }
        break;
    case WM_CREATE:
         CreateWindow(
            L"STATIC",
            L"This application demonstrates delayed clipboard rendering. "
            L"When clipboard data is requested, it will cause a delay of 1 minute, "
            "so that the receiving app displays a 'not responding' message.",
            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
            10, 10, 600, 100,
            hwnd,
            nullptr,
            reinterpret_cast<LPCREATESTRUCT>(lParam)->hInstance,
            nullptr);

        if (OpenClipboard(hwnd)) {
            EmptyClipboard();
            SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, nullptr); // Delayed rendering
            CloseClipboard();
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int APIENTRY wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPWSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {

    constexpr wchar_t CLASS_NAME[] = L"SampleWindowClass";

    WNDCLASS wc = {};
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;

    RegisterClass(&wc);

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,                              // Optional window styles.
        CLASS_NAME,                     // Window class
        L"Delayed Clipboard Rendering", // Window text
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,            // Window style

        // Size and position
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 640, 120,

        nullptr,       // Parent window    
        nullptr,       // Menu
        hInstance,     // Instance handle
        nullptr        // Additional application data
    );

    if (hwnd == nullptr) {
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);

    MSG msg = {};
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}


Nice PoC Thomas! Clearly demonstrates the bug.

@Neitsa: thank you for the feedback. Much appreciated.

Sorry for the delayed answer. Thank you very much. I guess it's not really possible to find out the reason only with the memory dump in my case but you showed a very nice example how to repro these kind of issues.
